# Colors in ImageMarker

Tags: color, image

The symbol ImageMarker (new in 10.4) seems to ignore color commands:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}];
corners = ImageCorners[img, 5, .005, 5];
HighlightImage[img, {Opacity[1], Blue, ImageMarker[corners, "Star"]}]
```

[image]

The the above result the stars should be blue not white.

Comment: Please post code so that we can reproduce the problem. Use `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}]` for example for the image if you want to.

Comment: @C.E. Added the dummy image for you.

Comment: `ImageMarker` is undefined; `ImageMarkers` does exist, but I get an error message in Mathematica 10.3: "Expecting either an image or graphics with dimensions {512,512} or a list of positions..."

Comment: I think it's new in 10.4

Comment: ok, that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}];
corners = ImageCorners[img, 5, .005, 5]; 
marker = Graphics[Module[{angle, n, p1, p2}, angle = Pi/n; n = 5; 
p1 = Table[{Cos[i 2 Pi/n], Sin[i 2 Pi/n]}, {i, 1, n}]; 
p2 = Table[{Cos[i 2 Pi/n + angle], Sin[i 2 Pi/n + angle]}, {i, 1, n}];     
{Red, Scale[Rotate[Polygon[Riffle[p1, 3 p2]], -angle/2], 1]}]];
Show[img, ListPlot[corners, PlotMarkers -> Show[marker, ImageSize -> 15]]]
```

[image]

Comment: [My God, it's full of stars!](https://f1.bcbits.com/img/a1968006109_10.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Using 12.3.1 here. You can specify a Graphics object as the ImageMarker and then have full control of its appearance. Caveat: I have not been able to use a star.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}];
corners = ImageCorners[img, 5, .005, 5];
HighlightImage[img, ImageMarker[corners, Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.02]]}]]]
```

[image]